# How to change text color for terms of service in firebase ui

Tags: android, firebaseui

[image]

Trying to change the text color of the words that go with the ToS and Privacy Policy on Firebase UI. I have tried adding text color to the theme in the styles to no avail.

```
 <style name="login_style" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/login_background_reduced_comic</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this replace textColorTertiary with any color

```
> <style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI"> <item
> name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/white</item>
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text1 = "By continuing, You are indicating that you accept our ";
String text2 = "<font color='#EE0000'>Terms of Service</font>"; //Specify your with color='#XXXXXX'
String text3 = " and ";
String text4 = "<font color='#EE0000'>Privacy Policy</font>"; //Specify your with color='#XXXXXX'
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text1 + text2 + text3 + text4));
```

Comment: Hi Where would i add that since the text comes from firebase ui and isnt a textview i access directly